# Any way to fix Cathedral crash in Fallout?

Tags: fallout, windows-xp

I really searched it before on web. I can't get to the 3rd level in Cathedral (Master's Lair). All the solutions I found were from [a very old thread in No Mutants Allowed](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6911). Nothing worked for me and the last one I tried corrupted all my savegames. There was nothing I could do. I watched the ending from Youtube.

I know there are people who finished in XP without a problem. I want to give it another try if  it will work. I am done with that stupid thread. It's 6 years old they kept merging it with every useless solution possible. If somebody here solved it , please explain how you did it with details. If you didn't have a problem, explain if you did something after installation.

- I patched the game to 1.1 before I
  started playing so it may be the whole
  problem. v1.0 may have a gameplay without any problems, I don't know.
- Entering area with too many items. I
  reloaded to an older save and entered
  area with less than 10 items, it
  didn't work.
- Using this
  [fix](http://teamx.ru/node/171). It
  corrupted all of my savegames. Thanks a
  lot
- Patching game to 1.2 after problem,
  didn't help too.

I hope it doesn't get closed, actually I am so desperate I had to take my chance. I took a quick look at FAQ, nothing is restricted about fixing bugs.

Additional info: Same problem happens on military base. I ended up playing Cathedral before there. I tried my luck there after learning about it, I managed to get in without a crash one time, yet there were times it crashed the same way.

**Update:**

I started a new game with the patches that corrupted my saves (1.2 and fix and maybe an unoffical patch). I made my way to Master's Lair after getting a level (needed for picking the door) and area loaded. So I'm giving it another try, I will post the result.

Comment: Are you running the original version of Fallout, or the GoG version?

Comment: Original version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished it. Didn't do more than what I wrote down in question so I'm not sure which is the solution. Probably it was the fix that corrupted my savegame.

Just in case I left all my companions before Base or Master(except Dogmeat,he died while passing force fields). I didn't have more then 10 items. It didn't crash even once. It can be done.